# PDF opening from a blob - Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

First of all I have tried all answers given in the stack overflow. So please do not consider this as a duplicate.

I have angular JS application talking to our company back-end using our own middleware API. One of those APIs returns a PDF in its response. I am using following code to display it.

**Service**

```
....
$http({
      url: aAPIname,
      method: "POST",
      data: req,
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
      headers: oHeaders,
   })
   .success(function(data, status) {                         
       deff.resolve(data);
   })   
  ....
```

**Controller**

```
var file = new Blob([data], {
                  type: 'application/pdf'
            });
var url = ($window.URL||$window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
var trustedURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
$window.open(trustedURL);
```

the problem is the opened window says "Failed to load PDF document" time to time (about 50% of the time). The same PDF opens up sometimes but not in the next try.

I tried response type "blob" as well as "arraybuffer" but, both gives the same result.

Anyone having any clue or idea on few more things I can check!

Ish